# I post a photo to my facebook page, but it doesn't show

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to upload a photo from my server to an album on my page.
I have the following code to send the photo:

```
$argsFeed = array(  'source' => '@' .$FILE_PATH,
                    'published' => true,
                    'message' =>    $caption);
try {
        $imageId2 = $facebook->api('/'.$ALBUM_ID.'/photos', 'post', $argsFeed);
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $result['status'] = "error";
        $result ['message'] = $result ['message'] .  ' ||| error posting photo to page 164264490295119. facebook says: <BR/>' . json_encode($e->getResult());
    }
```

I have the following permissions:
publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages

I always get success for the api-call, with a photo id, but the photo doesn't go anywhere.
The exact same photo was posted to my (the user's) wall as well, so the photo can't be the problem.
my guess is that it does get posted somewhere, since there's no exception, only I don't know where it's posted.
anyone has a clue?

I get photo-id's like this one:
10151091881973938,633203937_10151091735008938
but I don't know what to do with them - how do I look them up in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to diagnose this without some more context. Is $facebook->api performing a POST?

However, the fact that your retrieving photo-ids without image extensions leads me to believe that your problem could be that the image extension isn't making its way to the Facebook POST; thus you can't display an image that doesn't have a .jpg or .png extension. This would explain why it accepts the file as it is of type=image

Comment: The photo-id is just a Graph object id, why would it contain an image extension? Nope, the id as posted is correct, see my answer.

Comment: CBroe is right - the photo-id is a representation of the photo in the graph. Moreover, I send the EXACT same path ( `'source' => '@' .$FILE_PATH` ) when I post to the user's wall - and it works.

Comment: yes - as far as I can tell, $facebook->api performs a POST.
I'm new to PHP, so I don't know how to monitor what's happening on the server when it's running (it's hosted by heroku.)

Answer (score 0):

> I get photo-id's like this one: 10151091881973938,633203937_10151091735008938 but I don't know what to do with them - how do I look them up in the graph?

The first part before the comma is definitely your photo’s id in the Graph.

That’s your photo object on the Graph:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=10151091881973938

That’s one of the actual image URLs on Facebooks CDN:
https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/283597_10151091881973938_1730322674_a.jpg

And that’s the display URL of your photo on facebook.com displaying it as one of your photos in your album:
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151091881973938&set=p.10151091881973938&type=1

The second part, `633203937_10151091735008938` is obviously your user id combined with your photo’s id. Did you get them all as one string, as you posted them, `photo_id comma userid underscore photo_id`, or did you just post them as this?

Normally I would expect just the photo id to be returned from a successful photo post through the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this helps a lot. I'm a little less the dark now.
One thing though - the part after the underscore **is not** the photo-id - it's similar, but it's something else. the graph explorer doesn't show anything about it - it says "Unsupported get request.".

Comment: Also,
I've noticed that if I quarry for the photo id in the graph explorer - i get "false".
I also got "false" after deleting a photo I successfully posted.
So my current theory is that the photo gets through to the page, and the page deletes it immediately after the call is done.
Perhaps there is some kind of page configuration i'm missing, although I've looked.

Comment: You’re right of course, it’s not the same photo id the second time, I didn’t look careful enough. Where/how did you get those values anyway? As for page settings, check that you have both “Everyone can post to {page}'s timeline” and “Everyone can add photos and videos to {page}'s timeline” enabled.

Comment: Yes, I've got maximum permission allowed on the page, including what you wrote.
Next I'm going to try the deprecated REST api.